# Ripping cd at multiple mp3 bit-rates at once using abcde

Tags: audio, ripping, abcde

I've been trying to rip *mp3* copies of my cds using `abcde`. My issue is that I want to rip two sets of *mp3s* at two different bit-rates. 
One high bit-rate set for playback on my computer, and another lower bit-rate set for playback on mobile devices that have small storage capacity.

Currently I run:

```
abcde -o mp3:"-b 320" && abcde -c .abcdelow.conf -o mp3:"-b 128"
```

...which technically works, but is annoying because I have to enter the same information twice, and really isn't feasible if I have to hand enter the album data.  I would like to do this with one command so that I only have to enter the information one time.

My config file:

```
MP3ENCODERSYNTAX=default
FLACENCODERSYNTAX=default

LAME=lame
FLAC=flac

# Taggers, rippers, replaygain etc:
ID3=id3
ID3V2=id3v2
MID3V2=mid3v2
EYED3=eyeD3

#This line is the only difference between my two conf files.
OUTPUTFORMAT='low___${ARTISTFILE//_/ }/${ALBUMFILE//_/ }/${TRACKNUM//_/ } ${TRACKFILE//_/ }'
```

Comment: It seems as though the `abcde -o mp3:"-b 320" && abcde -o mp3:"-b 180"` would overwrite the  320 bitrate *mp3* with the 180 bitrate  *mp3*.  Testing on my system confirms it.

Comment: You are right, I actually run a script to rip my cds and I forgot that I pass in a second config file in the second command. This config file matches the previous except it pre-pends a low_* to the folder name. Sorry for that oversight. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

I use `abcde` for a similar purpose, but I use Ogg (or FLAC) for my high quality recordings and mp3 for the low quality. For example:

```
abcde -N -V -o ogg,mp3
```

Would that work for you?